# In a linux kernel mode, how can I detect a process?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I need to create a user-mode process. This process has to be detected in kernel mode to be sent to a FIFO queue (SCHED_FIFO) in the Linux kernel.

I have been investigating and if you use the function `void scheduler_tick(void)`, which is located in core.c (I think scheduler_tick is called by the system each tick of the clock of the cpu), I can capture the process.

My question is if this is correct, or if there is any better way.

Scheduler_tick code: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=scheduler_tick

The work is based on a multilevel queue, in which a series of diferente processes will be introduced(we have: payment processes, cancellations processes, reservations processes and event processes). These processes have different priorities in to the system.

Therefore when I created a process, for example payment process, i need detect the process, because i need know what type it is your priority.

Hence to comment the idea of used the function void scheduler_tick to detect process.

I don't know if i explained well ...

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand.  Is that not what the 'normal' process loader does, or perhaps fork()?

Comment: Why do you want to hack the kernel when you don't know *very well* about [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) in userland thru [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)? It looks like a huge mistake. The rule of thumb is to **avoid kernel patching** when you can

Answer (score 2):

Creating a user process is not a kernel concern.
All the user processes that are created are forked from the init process or from its children.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that in the kernel. Actually, you have to keep that outside of the kernel.

What you need to do is either use [chrt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrt) in you init scripts or use [sched_setscheduler](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler) from your init program or daemon monitor.